# The GET method is not supported for this route while sending email through mailgun

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Validation is working but the data is not being saved in array or something like that because i am unable to pass the data into view.

*+My SendEmailConroller.php consists of:*

```
class SendEmailController extends Controller
{

    public function send(Request $request)
    {
     $this->validate($request,[
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:10',
        'messagefor' =>'required|min:5'
     ]);

        $data =array(
            'name' => $request->email,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'messagefor' => $request->messagefor
        );
        Mail::to('shishir.nepal.9@gmail.com')->send(new WelcomeMail($data));
        return back()->with('success','Thank you for contacting us');
        // return redirect()->to('/email')->with($data);

    }

    public function index(){
        return view('emails.welcome')
    }
```

+I am trying to Send data from form to email controller and then show in welcome.blade.php

+My Welcome mail consists of:

```
class WelcomeMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $data;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data =$data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('help@gmail.com')->subject('new seo for my page')->markdown('emails.welcome')->with('data',$this->data);
    }
}
```

And my web.php is:

```
    Route::post('/email','SendEmailController@send');
Route::get('/sendemail','SendEmailController@index');
```

And at last my welcome.blade.php

```
    @if($message=Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
<strong>{{$message}}</strong>
</div>
@endif


<p>Hi , This is {{$data['name']}}</p>
<p>I have some query like" {{$data['messagefor']}} "</p>
```

Comment: `dd($request->all());` to debug your data input

Comment: I don't see `strpost()` in the given code. Please update.